# Wtforms.fields.html5 DateField and TimeField placeholder

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

With a flask app, for the form:

```
...
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField, TimeField
...
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    date_posted  = DateField('Date',format='%Y-%m-%d')
    time_posted  = TimeField('Time',format='%H:%M')
```

How can I get it to return the current date and time as a placeholder? The date and timer picker will not allow the submit until a valid date is entered. As a default, I would like the page to refresh so that the date and time picker shows the current date and time, so the post can be submitted - even without changes.

[image]

```
@app.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(date_posted=form.date_posted.data,
                    time_posted=form.time_posted.data)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post', form=form, legend='New Post')
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `default` parameter to pass the default value for a form field. In your case, use `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the current date and time:

```
from datetime import datetime


class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    date_posted = DateField('Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', default=datetime.now())
    time_posted = TimeField('Time', format='%H:%M', default=datetime.now())
```

Or you can format the default value to the specific format:

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    date_posted  = DateField('Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', default=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    time_posted = TimeField('Time', format='%H:%M', default=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried that previously and doesn’t work. Because the date and time value are not valid on submit. There needs to be a placeholder in the datepicker and timepicker itself in order for the form to submit.

Comment: Are you sure? I just test it on my computer, it works as expected...

Comment: Maybe you can try to format the default value, see the updated answer.

Comment: Apologies, it does fill the datepicker and time picker. Though it fills it with the date and time when I ran the flask app. How can I get it to continuously update to the present date and time?

Comment: Just use JavaScirpt to get the current date and time then update it in a time loop.

Comment: If my answer solved your current question, please accpet it.

Comment: would you mind providing an example of Javascript to get the current date. Many thanks

Comment: That's a new question, please create a new question for it.